# Unity, how would you make animation clip from script, and make it play

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a quick question. For modding purposes, i need to be able to create animation clip from bunch of sprites, from the disk, and be able to play it. So far i only found out, how to create one, but to make it play is completely different story.

so far my test code looks like this.

```cs
Sprite[] sprites;
    
    void Start()
    {
        AnimationClip animClip = new AnimationClip();

        Animation anim = GetComponent<Animation>();

        sprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Sprite/punch2");
        Debug.Log(sprites.Length);
        animClip.frameRate = 5f;

        EditorCurveBinding spriteBinding = new EditorCurveBinding();
        spriteBinding.type = typeof(SpriteRenderer);
        spriteBinding.path = "";
        spriteBinding.propertyName = "Sprite";

        ObjectReferenceKeyframe[] spriteKeyFrames = new ObjectReferenceKeyframe[sprites.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < sprites.Length; i++)
        {
            ObjectReferenceKeyframe orkf = new ObjectReferenceKeyframe
            {
                time = i,
                value = sprites[i]
            };
            spriteKeyFrames[i] = orkf;
        }
        AnimationUtility.SetObjectReferenceCurve(animClip, spriteBinding, spriteKeyFrames);

        animClip.legacy = true;

        anim.clip = animClip;
        anim.Play();

    }
```

i have a long story problem with Animation. Whatever i do, it won't play anything. Not even from the editor.

So if anybody have done anything like that, maybe with Animator, please let me know. This thing really drains me out. Thx in advance.

Comment: does it not give any form of error or anything?

Comment: You cannot use `EditorCurveBinding` at runtime.  You also cannot use `AnimationUtility` at runtime.  Anything in the `UnityEditor` namespace is off limits.

Comment: @hijinxbassist OP doesn't state they necessarily need it on runtime/in a build (though of course current usage looks like it)

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
spriteBinding.propertyName = "Sprite";
```

but [`SpriteRenderer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer.html) has no such property called `Sprite`! It only has a property [`sprite`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer-sprite.html) but actually not even that is what Unity serializes and stores in the clip.

The actual backing **field** that is serialized and holding the value of `SpriteRenderer.sprite` internally is called `m_Sprite`.

You can see this by simply create an animation clip for a `SpriteRenderer` in the editor and open it as a raw text file. Example:

```
  - curve:
    - time: 0
      value: {fileID: 10913, guid: 0000000000000000f000000000000000, type: 0}
    - time: 0.1
      value: {fileID: 10905, guid: 0000000000000000f000000000000000, type: 0}
    attribute: m_Sprite
    path:
```

---

Anyway though, as mentioned already most of the things you are using there are from the `UnityEditor` namespace anyway which is only available within the UnityEditor itself and will be completely striped of when building the application.